# Find elements that are showing and hiding depending on the scroll height - python-selebium-webdriver

Tags: python, html, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I'm trying to automate my spendings&budget, but the website of the bank reveals/hides the element I am looking for, depending on the scroll height.

**Example**

This is when I am at the top of the page:

[image: This is when I am at the top of the page:]

And this is when I scrolled a little:

[image: This is when I am at top of the transaction page:]

**Problem**

I am trying to get all elements in this `role='transactions-group'` but, when I added an option for scrolling:

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
transactions = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    "//div[@role='transactions-group']")
print(str(transactions[0].text))
```

it just loaded everything, but it continued to find the items that in this case were on the bottom of the page.

So my question is: Can I do some kind of loop or something to fix this problem?

Comment: have you tried to find your desired element directly by xpath? or some other locater

Comment: @coderoftheday
Yeah, I have, but it still doesn't change the fact that not all the elements I want are loaded. Thanks anyway!

Comment: is what you want always in the html script?, because you can use webdriver wait, to wait for the element to visible,

Comment: @coderoftheday It doesn't matter how much I wait, but how much I scroll, when I am on the top of the page, there is one box full of transactions, when I am at half of the page, this firstly loaded 'box' now is not visible in the HTML. So I need like a loop or sth that stops at every box or sth like this.

Comment: can you explain your problem fully, and the outcome you want, maybe edit your question. if possible include some sought of exapmple

Comment: @coderoftheday I'm not sure how to explain it better if you don't look at: https://app.revolut.com/accounts/transactions